# Angularjs upload Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent returns false

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to upload files along with form data from Angularjs client to web api.  I found some reference code online and implemented the same way.  The first line of code in the Web API method is `if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
            }`

which returns false and returns back failure to client.  I don't know what I did wrong....

Below is the code in my Angularjs

```js
 var _uploadNotes = function (notes, files) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: "api/issue/uploadNotes",
                headers: { 'Content-Type': false },
                transformRequest: function (data) {
                    var formData = new FormData();                    
                    formData.append("model", angular.toJson(data.model));
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.files.length; i++) {
                        formData.append("file" + i, data.files[i]);
                    }
                    return formData;
                },
                data: { model: notes, files: files }
            }).
            success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                deferred.resolve();
            }).
            error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                deferred.reject();
            });

            return deferred.promise;
        };
```

Comment: @user124916 - didyou find resolution for this issue?

Answer (score 5):

Simply replace 
`headers: { 'Content-Type': false},` with `headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined},`

The entire code:

```js
 var _uploadNotes = function (notes, files) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: "api/issue/uploadNotes",
                headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined},
                transformRequest: function (data) {
                    var formData = new FormData();                    
                    formData.append("model", angular.toJson(data.model));
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.files.length; i++) {
                        formData.append("file" + i, data.files[i]);
                    }
                    return formData;
                },
                data: { model: notes, files: files }
            }).
            success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                deferred.resolve();
            }).
            error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                deferred.reject();
            });

            return deferred.promise;
        };
```

Comment: I'm in a similar situation as OP, but using Fetch API rather than AngularJS.  Unfortunately this answer didn't work.